# Create one plot for different functions with ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
x <- -5:5 #create sequence

y <- round(3^x,2)
y1 <- round(10*x*sin(x^2),2)
y2 <- round(x^3,2) 

res <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,y1,y3)) #combine the 3 functions

ggplot(res, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line()
```

I can't figure out, how to plot y,y1,y2 with ggplot2 in one plot as line graphs.

Comment: You define `y2` but use `cbind` on `y3`. You also need to call `library(ggplot2)` before running `ggplot(res, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line()`. When I fix those trivial issues, your code produces a line graph. Please show us the output/error you get, and describe in detail the output you want. Also, see [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) for how to plot multiple groups in one plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put all the values (`y`, `y1`, and `y2`) in the same column, and use a third column to `group` each set together.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- -5:5 #create sequence

y <- round(3^x,2)
res <- data.frame(x,y,g='3^x')

y1 <- round(10*x*sin(x^2),2)
res <- rbind(res, data.frame(x,y=y1,g='10*x*sin(x^2)'))

y2 <- round(x^3,2) 
res <- rbind(res, data.frame(x,y=y2,g='x^3'))

print(res)

ggplot(res, aes(x=x,y=y, color=g)) + geom_line()
```

The data frame `res` will look like this:

```
    x       y             g
1  -5    0.00           3^x
2  -4    0.01           3^x
3  -3    0.04           3^x
4  -2    0.11           3^x
5  -1    0.33           3^x
6   0    1.00           3^x
7   1    3.00           3^x
8   2    9.00           3^x
9   3   27.00           3^x
10  4   81.00           3^x
11  5  243.00           3^x
12 -5    6.62 10*x*sin(x^2)
13 -4   11.52 10*x*sin(x^2)
14 -3  -12.36 10*x*sin(x^2)
15 -2   15.14 10*x*sin(x^2)
16 -1   -8.41 10*x*sin(x^2)
17  0    0.00 10*x*sin(x^2)
18  1    8.41 10*x*sin(x^2)
19  2  -15.14 10*x*sin(x^2)
20  3   12.36 10*x*sin(x^2)
21  4  -11.52 10*x*sin(x^2)
22  5   -6.62 10*x*sin(x^2)
23 -5 -125.00           x^3
24 -4  -64.00           x^3
25 -3  -27.00           x^3
26 -2   -8.00           x^3
27 -1   -1.00           x^3
28  0    0.00           x^3
29  1    1.00           x^3
30  2    8.00           x^3
31  3   27.00           x^3
32  4   64.00           x^3
33  5  125.00           x^3
```

and the plot will be:

[image: ggplot 3 lines]

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same as Aziz

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- -5:5 

y <- round(3^x,2)
y1 <- round(10*x*sin(x^2),2)
y2 <- round(x^3,2) 


res <- rbind(
        data.frame(group = "y",  x = x, y = y ),
        data.frame(group = "y1", x = x, y = y1), 
        data.frame(group = "y2", x = x, y = y2)
    )

ggplot(res, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you very much (y)